# escaping a variable into a quote?

Tags: c++

i'm trying to make a function that outputs n amount of colored spaces or " ". I specifically need it to be a quote string thing (not s) because I'm sending as an argument to the system() function.

is there a way that I can use a char variable inside a string.

I need it to function like this(I know it won't work):

```
system("echo -e \"\e[45m _myCharHere_ \"");
```

this way I can make the spaces (" ") any size I choose by multiplying the char by what ever integer I choose.

This is probably a stupid question, but I don't know all the technical programming terms for these operations etc; so I can't google it.

Thanks

Comment: Besides the `system()` call, are you using `C` or `C++`?

Comment: There's no need to use system to print these ANSI colour codes to your terminal... just use `std::cout << "\033[45m " << myChar;`  (`\033` is the ASCII code for an escape character in octal, you could also use `\x1B` if you prefer hex).

Answer (score 1):

You may use something like:

```
// Assuming mychar doesn't need escape sequence.
std::string command = std::string("echo -e \"\e[45m ") + myChar + " \"";

system(command.c_str());
```

Or as mentioned in comment, write directly (and here myChar can be special char):

```
std::cout << "\033[45m " << myChar;
```